# Installing C++ DLL, Header files, and Lib files in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, dll, mingw, libraries

What I am trying to do is exactly like the instructions on this website:

http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/sdl/setup.html

The only problem is that I didn't download the version of Code Blocks that comes with the mingw32 compiler.  I got the latest release from http://www.equation.com/servlet/equation.cmd?fa=fortran and installed it in 'C:\gcc'.  So, the folders that it is asking me to move files into don't exist.

The article asked me to download this file:

SDL-devel-1.2.15-mingw32.tar

Then in that file move the 'include\SDL' folder into the 'C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\include'.  (I don't have a CodeBlocks\include folder)

It then asked me to move the 'SDL.dll' to 'C:\Windows' which I was able to do.

Finally it wanted me to copy the contents of the 'lib' folder into the 'CodeBlocks\lib' folder.  (Another folder I don't have because I installed my compiler separately from the Code Blocks install)

Since I installed my compiler at 'C:\gcc' I tried to add the files into the 'C:\gcc\include' and 'C:\gcc\lib' files, but that didn't work.

I am not very familiar with the process of using 3rd party libraries.  I usually use Java where you can just stick the .jar file in with your code.  Do I need the .dll, include, and lib files.  Where do I actually need to put them?  I would also appreciate knowing why as well?

Comment: Do you have a `\CodeBlocks` folder? Just create the include and lib directories.

Comment: I could do that, but how would my compiler know to look in that folder.  The `\CodeBlocks` folder holds the compiler in the given example, but my compiler is in `C:\gcc`.  Would it still know to look in `\CodeBlocks`?

Comment: I don't know if you still need help with this, but somewhere in the properties for your project, there should be a list of include directories and library directories. Directory paths with header files you want to use go in the list of include directories; library paths with libraries you want to use go in with the respective directory. I'm probably not explaining it well, though. Try a Google search?

Comment: I was able to get it working with the MinGW compiler that comes with codeblocks, so I just gave up on using the release of GCC that I had put on the computer seperately.